# How to add strings to the combo box in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am working on MFC and I want to add strings to combo box. 
Unlike adding in the data (hard coding in the properties of combo box in resource view), I want to add them to string table and my c++ code has to load the string.

Please give suggestions.

Comment: Use `LoadString` to load the strings, and `your_combo_box.AddString` to add them to the combo box.

Comment: My combo box is defined as some ID in the dialogue box part of MFC and then data is given in the data field. I want to add the values as strings in my resource file

Comment: That sounds like it's in a dialog. If so, you need to associate a variable with it. Right click on the control in the dialog, and select `Add Variable...`, then add a variable associated with the control. Then the code for the dialog can manipulate the control via that variable as outlined above.

Comment: can I use any DDX_ function so that I can put some array or strings ?

Comment: That's probably worth asking as a separate question. Offhand, I don't remember, and asking it separately is likely to give it more visibility than here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- Add combo box to your dialog control
- Right click combo box , goto class wizard and add member variable of type CCombobox [control varable]
-This will add DDX_Control entry
- Now call variable_name.AddString to add strings to your combo box at runtime.
- If you want to use strings from string table then use Loadstring to load a string from string table first.
- Then call variable_name.AddString again ...

.... Have I cleared your doubts ???
```

Comment: Cool I got it, So I got the reference to the control box CCombobox * and then added the string

I have to make sure I remove the hard coded data and add the strings from my code.